# strange behavior of string.CompareOrdinal

Tags: c#, .net

```
        Console.WriteLine(string.CompareOrdinal("aaaaa", 3, "bbbb", 1, 0));
        Console.WriteLine(string.CompareOrdinal("aaaaa", 1, "bbbb", 3, 0));
        Console.WriteLine(string.CompareOrdinal("aaaaa", 1, "bbbb", 2, 0));
```

When I compile and run this code, sometimes it prints

```
0
0
0
```

(what is expected)
and sometimes

```
-1
-1
0
```

(what is really strange, as 2 empty substrings must be equal)

The second kind of output happens in one of my programs, and I have no idea why. I'm compiling it for .NET 4.5.1 AnyCpu with VS2013. Have anyone experienced similar bug? Any idea, why it might happen?

Comment: You are complaining about empty strings misbehaving but posted code that doesn't use empty strings.  Posting **real** code is essential.

Comment: I don't get why sometimes it would print one thing and sometimes another, but you have specified a 0 length so they are always equal.

Comment: @Hans Passant, I'm talking about substrings. All code is above.

Comment: @mike z, exactly. It must always print zeros, but it doesn't.

Comment: Looks like you are right. A length of 0 is explictly specified to return 0. But: I find it hard to believe that the code above is in a real program; it uses constants and has no use - so I suspect that the real code is something different and your simplified example is maybe oversimplified..

Comment: @TaW, this example shows exactly the same incorrect output.

Comment: If that is so you have found a bug. Create a minimal project to reproduce and pass it up to MS. For your application, use a workaround - checking for Length != 0 should be easy..

Comment: When I build I get the expected output of 3 0's; I've tried rebuilding a bunch of times and have never gotten anything but 0's.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I wasn't completely correct about bitness. One of applications had a "32 bit preferred" option set, and actually running in 32 bit mode. So, this is the reason: 32 bit application prints all zeroes, and 64 bit application prints "-1 -1 0". However, this is only a part of the answer. I still need an explanation why this happens. Better answers are welcome.

UPD I've reported this to Microsoft https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/871055/incorrect-behavior-of-an-application-in-64-bit-mode

UPD2 .NET 4.6.1 - the problem remains; Microsoft has silently deleted my Connect bugreport

Comment: It seems that the issue relates to Console.WriteLine, which has overloads for both Int32 and Int64. On x64 it seems that the compiler chooses the latter overload - even though String.CompareOrdinal returns Int32 (as documented). See ...

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasics32bitAnd64bitConfusionAroundX86AndX64AndTheNETFrameworkAndCLR.aspx for an example (look for IntPtr).

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer could be found in the MSDN "remarks" about the String.CompareOrdinal method:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/es986b3k(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/es986b3k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> ... Because CompareOrdinal(String, String) is a static method, strA and strB 
>   can be null. If both values are null, the method returns 0 (zero), which 
>   indicates that strA and strB are equal. 
>   **If only one of the values is null, the method considers the non-null value to 
>   be greater**

Is it possible you're passing in a null string?

Comment: Ahh, my mistake. I thought you were showing example code, but might have been using variables in your actual implementation.